# Chrome extension content script not injected to iframes

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Our `manifest.json` contains:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [ "content-script.js" ],
      "run_at": "document_idle",
      "matches": ["https://*.example.com/*"]
    }
  ],
```

Content script gets correctly injected to our pages at `example.com` unless somebody embeds our page to iframe on his page. Is there a way for our extension to inject content script to all iframes pointing to `example.com` if we want to keep `"matches": ["https://*.example.com/*"]`? We know it is possible with `"matches": ["https://*/*"], "all_frames": true` but we don't want to ask for wider permissions.

Comment: [declarativeContent API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) with a selector like `iframe[src*=".example.com/"]` might help.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, I will check it in couple of days and will inform you if it helps :-)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8917593/32453